# Split of new line instead of line break in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to split a string on a new line in SQL. I know that we can use CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) to look for line change. But is there a way to look for a brand new line. I have been able to split string in SQL using this function I found online:

//This function will split on the delimeter and create a new column

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitIndex](@Delimiter varchar(20) = ' ', @Search varchar(max), @index int)
    RETURNS varchar(max)
    AS
    BEGIN
          DECLARE @ix int,
                      @pos int,
                    @rt varchar(max)

          DECLARE @tb TABLE (Val varchar(max), id int identity(1,1))

          SET @ix = 1
          SET @pos = 1


          WHILE @ix <= LEN(@search) + 1 BEGIN

                SET @ix = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Search, @ix)

                IF @ix = 0
                      SET @ix = LEN(@Search)
                ELSE
                      SET @ix = @ix - 1

                INSERT INTO @tb
                SELECT SUBSTRING(@Search, @pos, @ix - @pos + 1)

                SET @ix = @ix + 2
                SET @pos = @ix
          END

          SELECT @Rt = Val FROM @Tb WHERE id = @index
          RETURN @Rt     
    END
GO
```

I  can do a SQL string:

```
SELECT dbo.SplitIndex(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), Notes, 1) as Note1 FROM NotesTable;
```

Notes Column Example:

```
Hello
Say no to war

Help Ukraine
```

I want to split the string on the empty line rather than how it is working right now:

The function is returning `Hello`

Edit 1:

Looks like my question was not clear. I am adding this from the reply below:

I am saying that

```
Hello
Say no to war
```

Should show up as one column instead of 2 different columns. `CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)` splits as soon as it sees a line break. I want to split on an empty line

Edit 2:

I am on SQL Server 2012 which does not support `STRING_SPLIT`

Comment: I would suggest, in truth, binning the above function. Multi-line table value functions can perform poorly, and `WHILE` loops in SQL *do* perform *very poorly*. Why not just use `STRING_SPLIT`, which is available in all supported versions of SQL Server.

Comment: I am saying that 

`
Hello
Say no to war
`
Should show up as one column instead of 2 different columns. `CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)` splits as soon as it sees a line break. I want to split on an empty line

Comment: Ah, ok. You need to show that as an example explicitly in the question because right now it isn’t clear. Essentially you want to split on _two consecutive cr/lf pairs_.

Answer (score 0):

Accidental Discovery:

I realized that if I change the split from

```
dbo.SplitIndex(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), Notes, 1)
```

to

```
dbo.SplitIndex(CHAR(10)+CHAR(13), Notes, 1)
```

It now splits it on empty lines which is exactly what is needed. I am not sure why this works though. If anyone knows the difference please post below. As per my understanding. I will also add that the notes field are added from MS Access database like this:

```
 Notes = vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Notes
```

`vbCrLf` means Visual Basic Carriage Return Line Feed. But some reason it splits on Line Feed Carriage Return.

Note:

I am using SQL Server 2012. Please use the suggestions mentioned on comments above for more efficient solution.